# how to work with multiple json array in Spring boot JPA?

Tags: mysql, json, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I currently work with spring boot and JPA, and here is my DAO class :

```
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,String> {
    @Query("select x from User x")
    public List<User> findAllActivit();
}
```

from this Dao, if i access controller which explore this JpaRepository, the json data should looks like this :

```
{
  "id" : "56e74ac5-d40e-11e6-846c-308d99bdc4d0",
  "user_name" : "alexander",
  "user_password" : "e46fc836cca3acec03944314d1457c2ae6c68ef3",
  "user_real_name" : "alexander darmawan",
  "user_cuti_amount" : 9,
  "user_position" : "head of business analyst",
  "user_join" : "2012-09-10",
  "activityList" : [ {
    "id" : "185aeb3b-d52b-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0",
    "activity_date" : "2017-01-18",
    "activity_name" : "Reject Julia Eka Ananda's cuti"
  }, {
    "id" : "a22af0d9-d529-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0",
    "activity_date" : "2017-01-02",
    "activity_name" : "Accept Danu Nugraha's cuti"
  } ]
}
```

does anybody know the query which work to make json data above to be like this :

```
{
      "idfromuser" : "56e74ac5-d40e-11e6-846c-308d99bdc4d0",
      "idactivity" : "185aeb3b-d52b-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0",
      "activity_date" : "2017-01-18",
      "activity_name" : "Reject Julia Eka Ananda's cuti"
},{
      "idfromuser" : "56e74ac5-d40e-11e6-846c-308d99bdc4d0",
      "idactivity" : "a22af0d9-d529-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0",
      "activity_date" : "2017-01-02",
      "activity_name" : "Accept Danu Nugraha's cuti"
}
```

every help will be precious for me

Comment: JPA, and Spring data repositories, don't have anything to do with JSON. If you want to change JSON, then serialize other objects to JSON, or change the JSON mapping of those objects.

Comment: i still newbe, so i tried to change query to be like this @Query("select activityList from User x") and the result just expose list from activityList. then i think i just need to join it with id right? because there are 2 ids, is that possible to use alias?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data JPA has nothing to do with `JSON` conversion that you are trying to attempt. This needs to be done in `Java` once we get the results back from db, i.e. we need to `transform` the activity list from old format to new format as shown in below example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> value = objectMapper.readValue("{  \"id\" : \"56e74ac5-d40e-11e6-846c-308d99bdc4d0\",  \"user_name\" : \"alexander\",  \"user_password\" : \"e46fc836cca3acec03944314d1457c2ae6c68ef3\",  \"user_real_name\" : \"alexander darmawan\",  \"user_cuti_amount\" : 9,  \"user_position\" : \"head of business analyst\",  \"user_join\" : \"2012-09-10\",  \"activityList\" : [ {    \"id\" : \"185aeb3b-d52b-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0\",    \"activity_date\" : \"2017-01-18\",    \"activity_name\" : \"Reject Julia Eka Ananda's cuti\"  }, {    \"id\" : \"a22af0d9-d529-11e6-bd89-308d99bdc4d0\",    \"activity_date\" : \"2017-01-02\",    \"activity_name\" : \"Accept Danu Nugraha's cuti\"  } ]}", Map.class);

    List<Map<String, Object>> activityList = (List<Map<String, Object>>) value.get("activityList");

    List<Map<String, Object>> transformedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Map<String, Object> element : activityList){
        Map<String, Object> transformedElement = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        transformedElement.put("idfromuser", value.get("id"));
        transformedElement.put("idactivity", element.get("id"));
        transformedElement.put("activity_date", element.get("activity_date"));
        transformedElement.put("activity_name", element.get("activity_name"));
        transformedList.add(transformedElement);
    }

    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(transformedList));
}
```

Comment: you using object mapper, but how about if i want make it by List<User>. here is my controller `@RequestMapping("/useractivity")
    public List<User> findAct() throws Exception {
        return useri.findAllActivit();
    }` I dont know how to mapping it

Comment: In that case, you need to add `idfromuser` and `idactivity` fields to User class and set those fields before sending the response back. Or even better, create a new class called `UserDto`